# Django - grouping a manytomany field sum

Tags: django, django-models

Django 2.1, python 3.6

I have two models

```
house = (
    ('Clubs','Clubs'),
    ('Diamonds','Diamonds'),
    ('Hearts','Hearts'),
    ('Spades','Spades'),
    )

class Card(models.Model):
    id           = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    card         = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    number       = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    house        = models.CharField(choices=house)

class Deck(models.Model):
    id       = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    name     = models.Charfield(...)
    card        = models.ManyToManyField(Card, through='DeckCard')

class DeckCard(models.Model):
    deck = models.ForeeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.cascade)
    card  = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def number_sum(self):
        self._number_sum= self.card.aggregate(total=models.Sum('number'))['total']
        return number_sum
```

The property field `number_sum` successfully returns the correct count. However, I want to now group the sum by `house`?  Does anyone know how to do this?

I wasn't as clear as I should have been before and so I have expounded.

Where Card looks like it should

```
id...name........number...house
1....ace_diamonds..1......diamonds
2....two_diamonds..2......diamonds
3....three_diamonds..3....diamonds
4....four_diamonds...4....diamonds
...
52...king_Spades...13....spades
```

and Deck looks like

```
id...name
1...johnsdeck
2...bettysdeck
```

Suppose DeckCard looks like the following

```
deck..card
1...ace_diamonds
1...two_diamonds
1...ace_diamonds (yes there can be duplicates)
1...three_hearts
2...ace_hearts
```

Then the model `Deck` is each person's set of cards. `DeckCard` are the physical cards in the deck. and `Card` contains the properties on the card.

I want to have Deck give some stats about the deck. E.g. total numbers per house.

So in the example I want to have a total count and a count per house
Deck 1
Total: 7 (1+2+1+3)
Diamonds: 4
Hearts: 3
Spades: 0
Clubs: 0

Deck 2
Total: 1
Hearts: 1

This
`self._number_sum= self.card.aggregate(total=models.Sum('number'))` gives me a total count per deck, or in this case 7. However, I want to have a `group by` so that I can have a count per house in addition to the total. Does anyone know how to do this.

In the end, I want to put this in a api like so

```
{  
  card: ...
  numbers: {
            Total:1
            Diamonds:4
            Clubs:0
            Hearts:3
            Spades:0
            }
}
```

But that is not for this question. I'm pretty sure the best place to put this is on a `@property` field. I'm just throwing that out there so someone knows the end goal.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve? `C` is a charfield and what you can do is to count it, do you want to count how many `C` types?

Comment: I have completely updated my question, because it was too vague before.